# How to write unit test code for polling with Coroutine Job?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, polling

I am using polling for an API call.

```
private var pollingJob: Job? = null

fun myApi(){
   pollingJob?.cancel()

   pollingJob = viewModelScope.launch{
       while(true){
           val result = apiRepo.callApi()
           _myResult.postValue(result)
           delay(30000L)
       }
   }
}
```

It seems like, I can't test this method because of looping. Is there any better way to be able to test it?

I think,

1. It would be okay if I can test only calling it once and the value is set correctly.

maybe I can cancel polling job after calling it once.
And also, here _isLoading, is set two times in one loop. How can I check it?
2. Polling test, check if the method calls the api at the right time repeatably.

How can I test it?

Maybe, I might use Timer or something else to call the next apis. But, Is there any better way?

Comment: Were you able to get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would override the viewModelScope for testing using `Dispatchers.setMain` (or a test rule to that effect). However since the code you're running on the viewModelScope never returns, this causes your test to hang.
what you'd want to do is make the polling code run on the [backgroundScope](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-test-scope/background-scope.html) of your test.

this means the `Dispatchers.SetMain` method is insufficient, you will need to inject the background scope into your method. One way to do that is:

```
private var pollingJob: Job? = null

fun myApi(externalScope: CoroutineScope? = null){
   val scope = externalScope ?: viewModelScope // defaulting to viewModelScope if no external scope is provided
   pollingJob?.cancel()

   pollingJob = scope.launch{ // using scope instead of viewModelScope
       while(true){
           val result = apiRepo.callApi()
           _myResult.postValue(result)
           delay(30000L)
       }
   }
}
```

and your test would look something like:

```
@Test
fun test() = runTest {

    backgroundScope.launch {
        viewModel.myApi(this)
    }

    runCurrent()
    // asserts and verifications ...
    // using advanceTimeBy(your delay) and runCurrent() as needed to simulate time passing
}
```